# jconnect 7.07 vs Jconnect 5 for ase 12.5

Tags: jdbc, sybase, sap-ase, jconnect

Sybase Ase 15.7 comes with JConnect 7
Sybase Ase 12.5 comes with JConnect 5.

Is JConnect 7 backwards compatible with ASE 12.5?

Or should I run JConnect 5?

Comment: More importantly why are you running ASE12.5 which was end of life in 2012? Normally for higher versions of JConnect you would to run  internal stored procs which JDBC requires for metadata and potentially if these contain longer datatypes which were added with 15.0 you may find these don't work in ASE12.5 so the quick answer is unfortunately you'd have to try it.

Comment: Because OEM Lied to us hard when upgrading to 15...

Comment: Yeah the 12.5 to 15 jump is a big step in terms of query plan changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from their documentation [here](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBCON/jConnect+Driver+Overview) and [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc73430_1254/html/aserbsol/CHDHDFCI.htm).
I would say that it should work.